# AES_GMAC implementation

Tags: gcm

I need to implement AES_GMAC encryption and decryption in c/c++ programming language.

For the implementation, I have referred following document:
http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/gcm/gcm-spec.pdf

But It seems that it contains esoteric information specific for people with cryptographic background. I am belonging to a non-cryptographic group.

Can anyone help with the pseudocode for the implementation purpose ?

Comment: Do you want to implement sole GMAC or full GCM? Is this for learning purposes or for production related purposes?

Comment: It's not pseudo code, but [the GCM implementation of Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/doxygen/gcm_8cpp_source.html) seems pretty readable for me. The question of course is: if you already have a cpp implementation...

Comment: To elaborate on @SOJPM's comment, it seems suspicious that you would have any need to implement AES-GCM as a person with a non-cryptographic background. If this is for a class, it's curious that there would be an expectation of implementing such an algorithm without having previously analyzed the construction. So it, frighteningly, looks like you might actually be trying to implement this for a real-world use.